# How to monitor stats for AWS streaming videos on demand

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an AWS setup where HLS videos for streaming are stored on S3 and they are delivered through cloudfront. They are streamed through a react web front end and react native application I created.

I've been trying to find how I can get stats on what's streamed, like view counts, percentage watched etc...

I cannot for the life of me figure out where to start. I reached out to people on AWS IQ but are getting quotes in the multiple of thousands which for a free project is impossible. I'm happy to do the work myself but just need some guidance.

**What I have tried:**
In cloudfront there's the Reports & analytics section, yet this only seems to give a high level and doesn't break it down per file. If I could get a breakdown of these metrics per file then I would be able to calculate most of what I need.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreaciated! thank you.